# $? value does not match the exit code in my ksh script

Tags: ksh, exit-code

I have the following code snippet in my ksh script.

```
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]; then
   print Error...
   exit 1
fi
```

This block executes since I see the printed statement, but after the script, at the shell prompt, when I type `echo $?`, the output I get is 0.

Comment: Post the code snippet, from where you are calling the above code snippet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The above code snippet is simply in a .ksh script, and once code logic reaches it, it does the test. I am running the .ksh manually from the shell prompt: ./script.ksh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is not getting returned from the snippet mentioned.
I have written below code and run in ksh . the output was as expected

```
ajay@pavilion:~$ cat ajay.ksh
var=1
if [ $var == 1 ]
then 
    print "Error"
    exit 1
fi
```

output

```
ajay@pavilion:~$ ksh
$ ./ajay.ksh
Error
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Comment: I also tried a similar script on my linux machine with .ksh and it works as expected. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Unrecognized Check may be some your ksh is opening one more shell inside it and in that this code snippet is used

Comment: Hey, Ajay. Follow-up...the code I posted works fine...turns out earlier in my script, I was calling another script that would spawn processes that would complete successfully after my main script ends, removing this...now it works fine.